# Linear Algebra: Span

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I go about solving this question?

Consider the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $x+2y-z=0$. Find any two vectors $v$,$w$, such that their span will be identified on the plane.

Comment: Take any vector in the pane. Then another one which is not a multiple of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to find two vectors that span the plane.  You just need to find two linearly independent vectors whose coordinates satisfy $x+2y-z=0$.  For instance
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\1\\4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
satisfies $2+2\cdot 1-4=0$.  Find one more that is not a multiple of this vector and you will be done.